# convert list to dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with column header & data. I am trying to convert this file data into pandas DataFrame.

File:

```
#Columns: TargetDoc|GRank|LRank|Priority|Loc ID
aaaaa|1|1|Slow|8gkahinka.01
aaaaa|1|0|Slow|7nlafnjbaflnbja.01
```

I wrote below code:
Firstly, I converted each line and trying list to convert Dataframe:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

with open("DocID101_201604070523.txt") as raw_file:
    full_file_text = raw_file.readlines()

raw_file.close()

data_list = list()
for l in full_file_text:
    if i.startswith('#'):
        labels = l.strip().replace('#Columns: ','').split('|')
    else:
        data_list += l.strip().split('|')

df = PD.DataFrame.from_records(data_list,columns=labels)
```

But I got error on df:

> AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns.

What's wrong with my code or is there any better way convert to dataframe ?

Comment: Why not just `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='|')`?

Comment: After getting rid of `#Columns: `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your are contataining all row into one list with :

```
data_list += l.strip().split('|')
```

What you want is :

```
data_list.append(l.strip().split('|'))
```

This way, you will get a list of list of 5 elements.

Edit : But the solution above of using csv separator is highly recommended.

Comment: In real time, the file may also have lot of junk data and i need to clean the data before get this structure. So I can't directly use read_csv and I need to create another temp file in order to use read_csv directly.

Comment: So that's your solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can just read in the file using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) with `sep='|'` and then fix the first column name as a post processing step using `rename`:

```
In [228]:
import io
import pandas as pd    
t="""#Columns: TargetDoc|GRank|LRank|Priority|Loc ID
aaaaa|1|1|Slow|8gkahinka.01
aaaaa|1|0|Slow|7nlafnjbaflnbja.01"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='|')
df

Out[228]:
  #Columns: TargetDoc  GRank  LRank Priority              Loc ID
0               aaaaa      1      1     Slow        8gkahinka.01
1               aaaaa      1      0     Slow  7nlafnjbaflnbja.01
```

Now [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) the first column by passing in the first column name as the key for the passed in dict and `split` the string for the new column name:

```
In [229]:
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:df.columns[0].split()[-1]}, inplace=True)
df

Out[229]:
  TargetDoc  GRank  LRank Priority              Loc ID
0     aaaaa      1      1     Slow        8gkahinka.01
1     aaaaa      1      0     Slow  7nlafnjbaflnbja.01
```

So in your case:

```
df = pd.read_csv("DocID101_201604070523.txt", sep='|')
```

and then `rename` like the above

Comment: Exactly. The point is that this is structured data and does not need to be treated like a text file.

Comment: Hi, real time the data is not structured and I am using below:

Comment: well nothing in your question stated this